# BeautifulSoup replace single quote( ' ) with ( â€˜ ) when writing to csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to **scrape** data from a website and the original text is in form of -
"The 'Hello, World' event", but when i try to extract it using html.parser and write it to csv file it becomes "The â€˜Hello, Worldâ€™ event", I want it to be written to csv in original form. Below is my code -

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
data = get_data(soup)
with open('The-Hindu-Dataset.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="UTF-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Can you include the original url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's written correctly. Your viewer is using the wrong encoding. Set that program to UTF-8, or try encoding='utf-8-sig' instead, esp. if you are on Windows. That writes a signature that editors like Notepad and Excel will detect and automatically decode as UTF-8.

Example:

```
#coding:utf8
import csv

with open('test1.csv','w',encoding='utf8',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['The ‘Hello, World’ event','你好，世界！'])
    w.writerow(['The ‘Hello, World’ event','你好，世界！'])

with open('test2.csv','w',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['The ‘Hello, World’ event','你好，世界！'])
    w.writerow(['The ‘Hello, World’ event','你好，世界！'])
```

test1.csv:

[image: Incorrect Excel display]

test2.csv:

[image: Correct Excel display]

The files are otherwise encoded identically except for the signature hinting at UTF-8-encoding.  Windows will assume a localized default encoding (typically Windows-1252) without it.  Even my hex compare tool assumed Windows-1252:

[image: Hex compare of files]

A better editor (such as Notepad++, or newer versions of Notepad) will display both files correctly.

Comment: Thanks man, changed the encoding of Excel and it displayed correctly!